# Add graphstream graph to jpanel with 'intellij.uiDesigner'

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphstream

I'm trying to add a `GraphStreams` graph to a `JPanel` using `com.IntelliJ.uiDesigner`, and I'm not sure how to initialize the graph's panel without getting the warning

```
Assignment to UI-bound field will overwrite field generated by UI Designer.
Inspection info: Reports assignments to fields which are bound to components in UI Designer forms.  
Such assignments will cause the component setup code generated by UI Designer for such fields to be ignored.
```

This is my code:

```java
public class Demo extends JFrame{
    private JPanel graphPanel;
    private JPanel label;

    public Demo(){
        System.setProperty("org.graphstream.ui.renderer", "org.graphstream.ui.j2dviewer.J2DGraphRenderer");

        Graph graph = new MultiGraph("Tutorial 1");

        Viewer viewer = new Viewer(graph, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_ANOTHER_THREAD);
        graphPanel = viewer.addDefaultView(false);  //    <====   this is the line that throws the warning

        ViewerPipe pipeIn = viewer.newViewerPipe();
        pipeIn.addAttributeSink( graph );
        pipeIn.pump();

        graph.addNode("A");
        graph.addNode("B");
        graph.addNode("C");
        graph.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
        graph.addEdge("BC", "B", "C");
        graph.addEdge("CA", "C", "A");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        demo demo = new demo();

        demo.setContentPane(demo.graphPanel);
        demo.setTitle("Kfir Demo");
        demo.setSize(300, 400);

        demo.setVisible(true);
        demo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks, sure! can you please elaborate on where I did not work according to the convention? or maybe even suggest an edit?

Comment: the class name jumps into attention, doesn't it ;)

Comment: @kleopatra my bad. fixed!

Comment: thanks for editing, should be also done in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to initialize swing components using `com.IntelliJ.uiDesigner` one
must use the
method `private void createUIComponents()`.
You can check out the example [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-form-initialization-code.html#328675c3).

And in this case, this have fixed it.

```java
public class Demo extends JFrame{
    private JPanel graphPanel;
    private JPanel label;

    public Demo(){ }

    private void createUIComponents() {
        System.setProperty("org.graphstream.ui.renderer", "org.graphstream.ui.j2dviewer.J2DGraphRenderer");

        Graph graph = new MultiGraph("Tutorial 1");

        Viewer viewer = new Viewer(graph, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_ANOTHER_THREAD);
        graphPanel = viewer.addDefaultView(false);

        ViewerPipe pipeIn = viewer.newViewerPipe();
        pipeIn.addAttributeSink( graph );
        pipeIn.pump();

        graph.addNode("A");
        graph.addNode("B");
        graph.addNode("C");
        graph.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
        graph.addEdge("BC", "B", "C");
        graph.addEdge("CA", "C", "A");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        demo demo = new demo();

        demo.setContentPane(demo.graphPanel);
        demo.setTitle("Kfir Demo");
        demo.setSize(300, 400);

        demo.setVisible(true);
        demo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```